# ReactNative- Writing expression for MapBox icon not working

Tags: react-native, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to create an expression to define two different icons for features on a symbol layer:

```js
mapPinLayer: {
      iconAllowOverlap: true,
      iconAnchor: 'bottom',
      iconSize: .05,
      iconImage: [
            'match',
            ['get', 'isUser'],
            1,
            ["image", "../pin.png"],
            0,
            ["image", '../pin2.png'],
            ["image", '../pin2.png'],
      ],
      iconRotate: 180,
    }
```

However, The icons do not show up for some reason. There are no errors, it just fails silently.

Is there a proper way to create an image from a path?